# What is the alternative code to if (isset ($_POST) && !empty ($_POST) to avoid warnings?

Tags: php, forms, variables, globals

I am trying to insert some php code to my WordPress website but it gives security warnings perhaps due to directly accessing `$_POST` variable.

Instead of `$name = $_POST['name'];`, I can use `$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` however I am not able to figure out what alternative piece of code I should use instead of `if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) { //some code }`?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What security warnings and where?  Please add that detail to your question. If you are linting your PHP with a tool like PHPCS you will likely see a "super global" warning, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter_input` is the proper way to go. If it doesn't return anything valid, it will return `null`:

```php
$myvar = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'something', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

if ( empty( $myvar ) ) {
    // Do whatever you would have done for ! isset( $_POST['something'] )
}

// Use $myvar
```

`filter_input` won't throw any notices if the requested index isn't found, so it's like having `isset` built-in to the function.

**Edit:** just be sure to use a `FILTER_` to sanitize or validate, and note there are some gotchas that are documented in PHP's documentation about these. For most general use-cases they should work fine, but always validate your user input appropriately once you have it (the same as you would when getting it directly from `$_POST`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me solve my problem. There is one more similar issue, using $_SESSION variable causes a 403 error on my website, such as using $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id, or $_SESSION['message'] = "Some Message" like statements. Is there some alternative statement like the one you posted in your answer?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the PHP [session functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php). Without knowing what the server log for the 403 was, it's hard to know what happened there. If you're still having trouble, try asking a new question (though if it's not WP-related, use stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Though the error was not caused by accessing $_POST variable directly, but I was able to write the alternative to `if(isset($_POST))`.

Firstly, you need to give a name to the submit button in your form. Your form should look like,

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
   Some fields.
   <input type = "submit" name = "submit_button" />
</form>
```

And then on the php side,

```
$submit =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit_button');
if (isset($submit)){
       //some code.
}
```

Hope this helps someone.